# Autoencoder outputs B&W images from color

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

We are in the process of training an AE on CIFAR10 images. We used the following architecture:

```
class OurAE(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, z_channels):
        super(OurAE, self).__init__()
  
        self.tot_diff = None
    
        self.in_channels = in_channels
    
        curr_channels = in_channels
    
        encoder = []
        channels = [3, 16, 64] + [z_channels]
    
        for out_channels in channels:
            encoder += [
                nn.Conv2d(in_channels=curr_channels, out_channels=out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=2),
                nn.ReLU()
            ]
            curr_channels = out_channels
    
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(*encoder)
    
        curr_channels = z_channels
        decoder = []
        channels = [64, 16, 3] + [in_channels]
    
        for out_channels in channels:
            decoder += [
                nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=curr_channels, out_channels=out_channels, kernel_size=4, padding=1, stride=2),
                nn.ReLU()
            ]
            curr_channels = out_channels
    
        decoder = decoder[:-1] # removing the RELU layer
        decoder.append(nn.Sigmoid())
    
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(*decoder)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.decoder(self.encoder(x))
```

We are not sure why but we always get black and white images.
We tried to replace the `Sigmoid` with `ReLU` in the last layer but to no avail.

These are the loss function and the optimizers that we used:

```
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(classifier.parameters(), lr=lr)
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

Here is an example of an input and output of the AE after training:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your input images are normalized to [0, 1]` range? You shouldn't use `ReLU`, stick with `Sigmoid` as it constrains the output to be in the correct range.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke I tried to do as you suggested though it did not work :/

Comment: If your input is normalized you should try a wider network (more channels) and larger latent space (z_channels) to capture the necessary information. What is z_channels set to currently?

Comment: 32 though we also tried 64. I thought it was plenty the shape of the latent vector is `[32, 8, 8]`

Comment: Try to go abruptly wide/deep first, to make sure the problem does not lie within the architecture/capacity.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I changed the loss function to 'mae'. That cleared the issue for me.